# VBA Use range with variable and stop it under a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of table and paste it in a new workbook. Columns A is always copied. In addition to it, I want to copy other ranges composed of other columns but as variable. For example, added to columns A, I copy columns C and E. Till now i succed to do it. What i want to add is to proceed that maximum 5 times and if I finish selecting the columns to copy, I exit. To be more clear, there is an exampel: 
I select column B, D, F and than copy them and paste them in a new workbook. So I stoped after three times and copy what I selected and go out.

this is my code:

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim col1 As String, col2 As String, x As String, col3 As String, col4 As  String, col5 As String, col6 As String
Dim copyrange1 As Range, copyrange2 As Range, CopyRange3 As Range, CopyRange11 As Range, CopyRange4 As Range, CopyRange5 As Range
col1 = InputBox("first column, if finish write 'done'")
If col1 = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    Else
    col1 = col1 & ":" & col1
    Set copyrange1 = Range(col1)
End If

col2 = InputBox("second column, if finish write 'done'")
If col2 = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    Else
    col2 = col2 & ":" & col2
    Set copyrange2 = Range(col2)
End If

col3 = InputBox("third column, if finish write 'done'")
If col3 = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    Else
    col3 = col3 & ":" & col3
    Set CopyRange3 = Range(col3)
End If

col4 = InputBox("fourth column, if finish write 'done'")
If col4 = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    Else
    col4 = col4 & ":" & col4
    Set CopyRange4 = Range(col4)
End If

col5 = InputBox("fifth column, if finish write 'done'")
If col5 = "done" Then
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    Else
    col5 = col5 & ":" & col5
    Set CopyRange5 = Range(col5)
End If

Set CopyRange11 = Union([A:A], copyrange1, copyrange2, CopyRange3, CopyRange4, CopyRange5)
CopyRange11.copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

It whould be much better if I use an If loop.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go like follows:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim col As String, colsAddress As String
    Dim nCols As Integer

    col = Application.InputBox("column index (leave 'done' to finsih)", "Columns To copy", "done", , , , , 2)
    Do While col <> "done" And nCols < 5
        nCols = nCols + 1
        colsAddress = colsAddress & col & ":" & col & ","
        col = Application.InputBox("column index (leave 'done' to finsih)", "Columns To copy", "done", , , , , 2)
    Loop

    If colsAddress <> "" Then
        Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Union([A:A], Range(Left(colsAddress, Len(colsAddress) - 1)))).Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate
        MsgBox ("copy finished")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()
    Dim colLetter As String, doneString As String
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = [A:A]
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
        If Not doneString = "done" Then
            colLetter = InputBox("first column, if finish write 'done'")
            If colLetter = "done" Then
                doneString = colLetter
                MsgBox ("copy finished")
            Else
                colLetter = colLetter & ":" & colLetter
                Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, Range(colLetter))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    copyRange.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution to this problem

```
 Sub Macro3()

 Dim ColNum As Long
 Dim Col As String
 Dim CopyRange As Range

 Set CopyRange = [A:A]

 For i = 1 To 5

     Col = InputBox("Column number " & i & ", if finish write 'done'")

     If Col = "done" Then

         MsgBox ("copy finished")

         GoTo ExitIteration

     Else

         Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Range(Col & ":" & Col))

     End If

 Next

 ExitIteration:

 CopyRange.Copy
 Workbooks.Add
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate

 End Sub
```